# Why is '@objc' required to check for protocol conformance in Swift?

Tags: objective-c, oop, swift

Apple's [*Swift Programming Language Guide*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/index.html) states that

> You can check for protocol conformance only if your protocol is marked
>   with the `@objc` attribute

Why is this necessary if I'm not interoperating with Objective-C?

Answer (score 8):

UPDATE for Swift 1.2

- As RyanM pointed out, there are language changes that have removed the need for the `@objc` keyword.

Indeed, the following simple example now works w/o the `@objc` keyword:

```
protocol Ap {
    func hello()
}

class A: Ap {
    func hello() {
        println("hello, world")     
    }
}

var a = A()
if (a as AnyObject) is Ap {
    a.hello()
} else {
    println("nope")
}

// hello, world
```

Furthermore, the linkage now only looks like this:

```
protocol-conformance-1-2:
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1213.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 228.0.0)
    @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
```

ORIGINAL:

Let's look at an example. Note that I also used extra `(varName as AnyObject)` calls, otherwise the compiler complained `'is' test is always true` -- since it knew exactly what the type was at compile time.

```
import Foundation

protocol Swifty {
    func s()
    //  protocol-conformance.swift:5:2: error: 'optional' can only be applied to members of an @objc protocol
    //          optional var a: Int { get }
    //          ^
    /*
    optional var a: Int { get }
    */
}

protocol SwiftyClass: class {
    func scl()
    //  protocol-conformance.swift:13:2: error: 'optional' can only be applied to members of an @objc protocol
    //          optional var a: Int { get }
    //          ^
    /*
    optional var a: Int { get }
    */
}

@objc protocol SwiftyConformance {
    func scon()
    optional var a: Int { get }
}

class SwiftyOnly: Swifty {
    func s() {
        println("s")
    }
}
class SwiftyClassOnly: SwiftyClass {
    func scl() {
        println("scl")
    }
}
class SwiftyConformanceOnly: SwiftyConformance {
    func scon() {
        println("scon")
    }
}
class SwiftyConformanceWithOptional: SwiftyConformance {
    func scon() {
        println("sconwo")
    }
    var a: Int {
        get { return 1; }
    }
}

println("swifty")
var swifty = SwiftyOnly()
//protocol-conformance.swift:49:26: error: cannot downcast from 'AnyObject' to non-@objc protocol type 'Swifty'
//if (swifty as AnyObject) is Swifty {
//   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^  ~~~~~~
/*
if (swifty as AnyObject) is Swifty {
    println("swifty is Swifty")
}
*/
//  protocol-conformance.swift:47:34: error: cannot downcast from 'AnyObject' to non-@objc protocol type 'Swifty'
//  if let s = (swifty as AnyObject) as? Swifty {
//             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^   ~~~~~~
/*
if let s = (swifty as AnyObject) as? Swifty {
    s.s()
}
*/
println("")

println("swiftyClass")
var swiftyClass = SwiftyClassOnly()
//protocol-conformance.swift:61:31: error: cannot downcast from 'AnyObject' to non-@objc protocol type 'SwiftyClass'
/*
if (swiftyClass as AnyObject) is SwiftyClass {
    println("swiftyClass is SwiftyClass")
}
*/
//protocol-conformance.swift:80:39: error: cannot downcast from 'AnyObject' to non-@objc protocol type 'SwiftyClass'
//if let s = (swiftyClass as AnyObject) as? SwiftyClass {
//           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^   ~~~~~~~~~~~
/*
if let s = (swiftyClass as AnyObject) as? SwiftyClass {
    s.scl()
}
*/
println("")

println("swiftyConformanceOnly")
var swiftyConformanceOnly = SwiftyConformanceOnly()
if (swiftyConformanceOnly as AnyObject) is SwiftyConformance {
    println("swiftyConformanceOnly is SwiftyConformance")
}
if let s  = (swiftyConformanceOnly as AnyObject) as? SwiftyConformance {
    s.scon()
    if let a = s.a? {
        println("a: \(a)")
    }
}
println("")

println("swiftyConformanceWithOptional")
var swiftyConformanceWithOptional = SwiftyConformanceWithOptional()
if (swiftyConformanceWithOptional as AnyObject) is SwiftyConformance {
    println("swiftyConformanceWithOptional is SwiftyConformance")
}
if let s  = (swiftyConformanceWithOptional as AnyObject) as? SwiftyConformance {
    s.scon()
    if let a = s.a? {
        println("a: \(a)")
    }
}
println("")
```

... and (without uncommenting the broken-code test cases), the output is:

```
swifty

swiftyClass

swiftyConformanceOnly
swiftyConformanceOnly is SwiftyConformance
scon

swiftyConformanceWithOptional
swiftyConformanceWithOptional is SwiftyConformance
sconwo
a: 1
```

So, the simple answer is just as the docs state: you need `@objc` for [protocol conformance testing](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-XID_426) (and [optionals](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-XID_428)).

In Swift, [objc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Attributes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH35-XID_529) is just a declaration attribute, which generally represent hints to the compiler or modify how code is generated.

But the longer answer then begs the question: "but why was the language or runtime written this way?", and that's harder to address; my guess is that the `@objc` attribute will generate bona fide Objective-C object/protocol references, and conformance testing is simply implemented using that within the runtime.

You can comment-in the code in the example above that's between /* and */ one at a time, and see when and where the compiler complains.

UPDATE: compiler and linker updates

If we compile the above: `xcrun swiftc -sdk $(xcrun --show-sdk-path --sdk macosx) protocol-conformance.swift` and check what it links to with `otool -L protocol-conformance`, we see

protocol-conformance:

```
/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1213.0.0)
/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 228.0.0)
@rpath/libswiftCore.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
@rpath/libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
@rpath/libswiftDarwin.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
@rpath/libswiftDispatch.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
@rpath/libswiftFoundation.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
@rpath/libswiftObjectiveC.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
@rpath/libswiftSecurity.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
```

... so I think it's more fair to say that to do these conformance tests, you need to interact with the Objective-C runtime, but I wouldn't necessarily say that you need to interact with Objective-C (which to me implies some amount of objc code that you'd have to wittingly write).

Look at a very simple protocol-using program:

```
protocol Ap {
    func hello()
}
class A: Ap {
    func hello() {
        println("hello, world")     
    }
}
var a = A()
a.hello()

//$ otool -L hello-world
//hello-world:
//  /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1213.0.0)
//  /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 228.0.0)
//  @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
```

... but if just try to implement an @objc protocol with no other changes:

```
@objc protocol Ap {
    func hello()
}
class A: Ap {
    func hello() {
        println("hello, world")     
    }
}
var a = A()
a.hello()

//$ xcrun swiftc -sdk $(xcrun --show-sdk-path --sdk macosx) hello-world.swift 
//hello-world.swift:1:2: error: @objc attribute used without importing module 'Foundation'
//@objc protocol Ap {
// ^~~~
```

... and then if we import Foundation:

```
import Foundation

@objc protocol Ap {
    func hello()
}
class A: Ap {
    func hello() {
        println("hello, world")     
    }
}
var a = A()
a.hello()

//$ otool -L hello-world
//hello-world:
//  /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1213.0.0)
//  /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 228.0.0)
//  @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
//  @rpath/libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
//  @rpath/libswiftDarwin.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
//  @rpath/libswiftDispatch.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
//  @rpath/libswiftFoundation.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
//  @rpath/libswiftObjectiveC.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
//  @rpath/libswiftSecurity.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
```

I would even say that the Swift standard library and runtime absolutely utilizes the Objective-C runtime, and expects access to defacto core Objective-C frameworks like Foundation for core features.

Comment: So the TL;DR is that it's because protocol conformance testing is implemented within the Objective-C runtime (not in Swift)? In other words — and this is the crux — protocol conformance checking *does* interact with Objective-C (even if "I'm not")?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius somewhat -- I updated above with my opinion, but the answer is basically "yes" -- you have to interact with the Objective-C runtime.

Comment: @RyanM: Provisionally unaccepted in light of [(reported) language changes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29655235/656912).

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius thanks for the heads up -- the new language features make things much simpler. I updated my answer with a simple example to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

Swift has evolved since the accepted answer, and the answer now is:

It isn't.

From [The Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-ID283):

> You can use the is and as operators described in Type Casting to check for protocol conformance, and to cast to a specific protocol. Checking for and casting to a protocol follows exactly the same syntax as checking for and casting to a type...

```
protocol PersonBasedView {

    var person: Person? {get set}
}

class EmployeeView : UIView, PersonBasedView {

    var person: Person?
}

// Elsewhere

var view = ...

if view is PersonBasedView { ... }

// or
if let personView = view as? PersonBasedView { ... }
```